# How to manually re-validate the Validations of the ValidationContext in ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I need to force the `ValidationContext` to re-validate its `Validations` / `ValidationRules` when a specific property of my ViewModel changes. I don't see any methods to trigger validation, e.g. a `Validate()` method. I'm using [ReactiveUI.Validation](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/user-input-validation/) framework.

Comment: https://www.reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui.validation.contexts/validationcontext/9efdc59f

Comment: @Jason That will force a re-validate, not just get the last state of Validation?

Comment: I assume so - "Returns if the whole context is valid **checking all the validations**."

Comment: @Jason Unfortunately upon testing, it doesn't appear to cause revalidation to occur. I think it just re-reads the current `IsValid` property values of each `Validation` / `ValidationRule` in the `ValidationContext.Validations` collection.

Comment: @Jason An alternative but equally helpful solution would be if there's a way to temporarily ignore / disable certain `ValidationRules`.